# Setting Up Qt 5

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, cmake, qt-creator

I downloaded and installed the community version of Qt 5.10 and Qt Creator for a C++ project I'm working on. I'm just wondering if I did something wrong during the installation because in my options, there is no cmake file, or any debuggers. Or am I supposed to set these up myself?

Comment: Do you have a _valid_ kit .. can you run a test?

Comment: That's what I was referring to. No valid kits upon startup. I downloaded Cmake and added it to a Kit. But I'm a bit confused on the rest.

Comment: Whats Yr OS .. how did you install Qt

Comment: I'm on Windows 10. I installed Qt from the website and used their online installer.

Comment: I now realize I failed to install MinGW along with the installation. I'm installing that and I'll report back